# Open a website on a pop up window using Javascript/typecript and close on successful login

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get data from website B to website A. This requires me to manually login to website B.
What I am trying to do is open a pop up of B from A, login to B and automatically close the pop up containing B.

The problem is B and A are cross domain and Javascript has security features which prevent me from using function that get the current URL of website B, detect a change in URL of B.

Is there any workaround this?

My code is as follows:

```
  private websiteBRedirect(){
    let popupWindow = window.open("websiteB", 'popup','height=' + 600 + ',width=' + 600 + ',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes');
    let timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);
    let url = this.authUrl[0];

    function checkChild() {
      if (popupWindow.closed) {
          window.location.href = url;
          clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here I am creating a popup variable called 'popupWindow' which loads the login page of websiteB (used websiteB instead of the actual confidential website). 
I want to check if user has successfully logged into website B and then close the pop up window.
After the pop up window is closed my code here changes my current URL (websiteA) to another URL if login is successful which I cannot unfortunately test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONP for cross domain requests,

JSONP simply refers to “JSON with padding”. It is essentially a JSON response wrapped around a callback function that is specified in the URL. For instance, the following a JSON response.

```
{ “username”: “sdaityari”, “name”: “Shaumik Daityari”}
```

The same response with a callback function specified as processData is as follows.

```
processData({ “username”: “sdaityari”, “name”: “Shaumik Daityari”})
```

That should help you to find out how to solve your problem, as you did not post any code I could work with.